# get dplyr or other packages without rtools

Tags: r

Is there anyway to install R-packages that need compiling without Rtools?

For example, if I want a specific version of the 'dlyr' package, can I download it pre-compiled?

I can't install Rtools or update R-studio, but I really need dplyr.

Comment: Typically CRAN only makes the pre-compiled versions available for the "current" version of R. You might try the [CRAN binary acrchive](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/). It doesn't have every version, but it does have a version that should in theory work for a given R version (but you'll also have to install dependencies yourself as well). I can't tell if the [RStudio Package Manager](https://www.rstudio.com/products/package-manager/) has combined packages available for every version or not but it might. What version of R are you running?

Comment: I'm on 3.5.1. I will check that link